# How to check if a rating bar is has been rated or not in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, toast, ratingbar

I have a rating bar in my app and I want to check if the user has rated on the rating bar or not. If it been has rated by the user then , an intent takes you to the next screen and if he has not rated then there is toast message which says "Please rate us!!"

Answer (score 8):

First, you have to set `android:rating="0.0"` to your `RatingBar` in xml. Then on button click check,

```
RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.ratingBar:
                 if(ratingbar.getRating() == 0.0){

                    //set what you want
                     }else{

                    //give error if ratingbar not changed
                     }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `onRatingBarChangeListener` and place the intent for the new activity inside it:

```
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromUser) {

            // place intent for new activity

        }
    });
```

Use the `RatingBar.getRating()` method to get the current rating. If it returns zero, then prompt the user to rate your app with a toast.

You can more about Rating Bar and its methods [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

Comment: `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` will be useless if we just want our rating on the RatingBar. I can only use `ratingBar.getRating()` and get the rating directly.

Comment: `getRating()` will give you the current rating. What if the user changes the rating? This listener will be called each time the user decides to update the rating. In any case, if you don't need to use it, then don't. Same goes for OP.